# Connection timed out when I try to connect posgrest sql server on digitalocen and azure function

Tags: python, postgresql, azure-functions, digital-ocean

I have a postgres database running on a digital ocean server. The database is protected by a firewall and ssl root certificate, I add the Outbound addresses provided by the Azure Function App to the database firewall and I am passing the certificate through the connection string.

```
pg_conn = psycopg2.connect(host= os.environ.get("PG_HOST"),database= os.environ.get("PG_DB"), user=os.environ.get("PG_USER"), password=os.environ.get("PG_PASSWORD"), port=os.environ.get("PG_PORT"), sslmode='require', sslrootcert = r'my-proyect/certificate.crt' )
```

But when I upload my function to the cloud the connection sends a timeout

```
Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, A connection time-out error is typically due to connectivity issues or networking issues.

- Firewall if not allowing the access to the port number which application has.

Here is the tool for troubleshooting these sort of issues is [portgry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/portqry-command-line-port-scanner-v2#step-1-port-status-test)

`portqry -n [hostname] -e [port number]`

- you can even add applications to Trusted Resources in Postgry SQL

[image]

Here is the [document](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/postgresql/how-to/secure/#firewalls) which has complete information about connection time out error.